# How to use TinyMCE Editor for one of my custom post meta field?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field, metabox, tinymce

I'm registering a new post type

```
 register_post_type('datasheet', [
     ....,
    'register_meta_box_cb'  => [ $this, "add_metaboxes" ]
 ]);
```

Adding metaboxes

```
  function add_metaboxes ( $WP_Post ) {  

    $id = $WP_Post->id;
    $english_description = get_post_meta("$id","datasheet_english_description");

    add_meta_box( 
      $id             = 'datasheet_english_description', 
      $title          = 'Scheda tecnica inglese',
      $callback       = function ( $WP_Post ) {

        wp_editor( $english_description, 'data_sheet_english_description', $settings =[
          'media_buttons' => false,
          "tinymce"       => true,
        ]);    
      }, 
      $screen         = "datasheet", 
      $context        = 'normal',
      $priority       = 'low', 
      $callback_args  = null 
    );
  }
```

As you can see I'm trying to use `wp_editor` function to add tinymce as editor for my custom field.

As result I can see my custom metadata field.
But I can edit only into the 'Text' tab, not into the 'Visual' tab.

Probably I must pass to TinyMCE some more arguments.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that I found that was due to a serious internal network problem, the .js/.css files was server damaged and so the editor was not serverd the right way to the browser.

Fixing communication problems also fixed this issue. No changes to the code.